# INSERT statement gives me '' empty string but it appears to need to be null

Tags: php, mysql, oop, null, insert

Ok, I have this class object in php where the INSERT statement is created such that it doesn't give a value for the ID, because that is meant to simply auto-increment when it gets passed to the database.  It used to work, now it's not.  in fact, it still works on my live server, but not on my localhost development environment.  My sql looks like this when it comes out:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (u_sess, user_id, school_id, teacher_id, test_id, holder_id, visible, date_created, last_updated) VALUES ('', '1', '1', '', '', '', '', '2019-09-19 22:18:58', '2019-09-19 22:18:58')Database query failed.
```

When I paste that into the SQL window of my phpMyAdmin it gives me more detailed feedback on the problem:

## 1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'u_sess' at row 1

So, I changed my INSERT statement to look like there's a NULL in the first position and that rolls the error down to the next '' empty string.  So, I'm guessing that the error is coming from the fact that my php object is producing an INSERT statement with empty strings in it, instead of NULL for all unknown values.  I don't know how to modify my php object properly to get it to recognize and redefine each '' as NULL.  I'm sure that would solve it because, when I change ALL the empty strings to NULLs...the thing finally inserts properly.

Here is my CREATE method:

```
        global $database;
        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
        $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
        $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
        $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
        $sql .= "')";
        echo $sql;

      if($database->query($sql)) {
        $this->u_sess = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider this `function`:

```
function handle($input) {
    return ((!$input) && ($input !== '')) ? "null" : $input;
}
```

Calling this `function` would yield the value you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Lajos!  I'm taking your advice or trying...and the downvote was certainly not me.  If you wouldn't mind helping me a bit further...I'm not that strong with how all this OOP works...I think I'm getting better with time, but I'd like your advice on how to weave your function into what I have here.  I mean, where, in the steps would be the best moment to send those attributes to your function?  And, how exactly would you write it?  

$attributes = $this->handle($attributes);

...just after the 

$sql .= ") VALUES ('";

...line?

Comment: @FredericPool no worries, all of us were beginners with OOP back in the day (except those who originally implemented it). With your current implementation, you will need to change the return to return ((!$input) && ($input !== '')) ? "null" : '"'.$input'"'; and not worry about the apostrophe in your query. As about the $attributes array, you can do something like foreach($attributes as $key => $value) $attributes[$key] = handle($value);

Comment: @FredericPool after you manage to solve this problem, you will need to ensure that you prevent SQL injection, by using PDO. It handles the logic we handle in the function called handle, so you will no longer need it and you will be able to create a parameterized query. Don't worry about your current work, when successful being rewritten again, it's called refactoring and the current step is important for your learning and confidence building.